# SQL query to count two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to MySQL queries and cannot find a way to do this. Hope you can help.

I would like to search two columns 'calldate' LIKE '2014-10-11' and 'channel' LIKE '%SIP/123456' in table asterisk_cdr then get a result count of number of channel rows found for the given date. Tried this but wrong syntax.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `asterisk_cdr` 
WHERE `calldate` LIKE '%2014-10-11%' 
AND `channel` LIKE '%SIP/4546975289%'
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: what are the data types of calldate and channel? can you share the structure of your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `COUNT` and a [SQL-Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM asterisk_cdr
WHERE calldate LIKE '%2014-10-11%'
     AND channel LIKE '%SIP/4546975289%'
```

Comment: Yes that worked! I did try this before but is had the columns is ''. Thank you so much. Now to get this to work in a php script with a small form!